# reading and processing files in parallel in R

Tags: r, file-io, parallel-processing, large-files

I am using the `parallel` library in R to process a large data set on which I am applying complex operations.

For the sake of providing a reproducible code, you can find below a simpler example:

```
#data generation
dir <- "C:/Users/things_to_process/"

setwd(dir)
for(i in 1:800)
{
    my.matrix <- matrix(runif(100),ncol=10,nrow=10)

    saveRDS(my.matrix,file=paste0(dir,"/matrix",i))
}

#worker function
worker.function <- function(files)
{
    files.length <- length(files)
    partial.results <- vector('list',files.length)

    for(i in 1:files.length)
    {
        matrix <- readRDS(files[i])
        partial.results[[i]] <- sum(diag(matrix))
    }

    Reduce('+',partial.results) 
}


#master part
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores(), type = "PSOCK")

file_list <- list.files(path=dir,recursive=FALSE,full.names=TRUE)

part <- clusterSplit(cl,seq_along(file_list))
files.partitioned <- lapply(part,function(p) file_list[p])

results <- clusterApply(cl,files.partitioned,worker.function)

result <- Reduce('+',results)
```

Essentially, I am wondering if trying to read files in parallel would be done in an interleaved fashion instead. And if, as a result, this bottleneck would cut down on the expected performance of running tasks in parallel?

Would it be better if I first read all matrices at once in a list then sent chunks of this list to each core for it to be processed? what if these matrices were much larger, would I be able to load all of them in a list at once ?

Comment: I don't see any reason to first read all the data and then process it. Your pipeline looks quite efficient for me (usually I use something similar). If you process many files, system load will become uniform after some time. What do you think is bottleneck? Computations or I/O?

Comment: @DmitriySelivanov I profiled my worker function, and the bottleneck is largely due to the readRDS() function. I'm thinking that this is happening because workers have to wait for others to complete reading the file so that they can start reading. I am not sure of how the operating system handles parallel readings, and I am wondering if loading all files data in memory would improve performance

Comment: The problem can be in compression. Do you use some compression? (`saveRDS` apply it by default). But I usually turn it off and things become much master.

Comment: @DmitriySelivanov I have just tried to add the argument compress=FALSE. Then, I compared reading a compressed file vs a non compressed file. Reading a compressed file is a bit faster contrary to what you said. So, no this didn't work for me unfortunately

Comment: Thats sad. Seems I/O is the largest part of the job. I can only suggest to play with delays on workers, so they won't read from disk in parallel. Something like different `Sys.sleep(some_time)` on each worker. But I don't expect you will accelerate your job for a considerable margin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of saving each `matrix` in a separate RDS file, have you tried saving a `list` of N matrices in each file, where N is the number that is going to be processed by a single worker?

Then the `worker.function` looks like:

```
worker.function <- function(file) {
    matrix_list <- readRDS(file)
    partial_results <- lapply(matrix_list, function(mat) sum(diag(mat)))
    Reduce('+',partial.results)
}
```

You should save some time on I/O and maybe even on computation by replacing a `for` with a `lapply`.

Comment: I am actually using k-fold cross validation with k as an input variable. Meaning that, with your solution, I would have to resave the folds in files depending on the folds split. This will add overhead to the computations. I actually just wanted to understand the ramifications of trying to read files in parallel (how would the operating system handle that, and if this might lead to bottlenecks, why ?) then in the second question I ask for an alternative to loading all data in memory (I was thinking of Hadoop and whether this would be a case where using a DFS is justifiable)

Comment: In your code, doesn't each of the files in `file_list` only get read by one worker? In that case, there shouldn't be multiple workers trying to read the same file. With respect to k-fold validation, depending of the value of 'k' it might be feasible to save the data in k files (one file by chunk) which wouldn't require re-saving.